# H infty optimization of transfer function matrix

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I have a two-dimensional (2 x 2) transfer function matrix like this:

[image]

The aim is to solve optimization problem:

[image: $$\min_{x, y} ||G||_\infty $$]

I used this code, but there is sth wrong:

```
   syms s
   s = tf('s');
   x = fmincon(@(x) norm([1/(x(1)*s+1), 1/(s+0.5); 3/(s+3), 1/(x(2)*s+2),inf),[1 1],[],[],[],[],[0 0],[2 2])
```

How can I treat this optimization problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is:

```
 x = fmincon(@(x) norm([1/(x(1)*s+1), 1/(s+0.5); 3/(s+3), 1/(x(2)*s+2),inf),[1 1],[],[],[],[],[0 0],[2 2])
                                                                          |
Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.
```

which is pretty clear. You forgot to close a bracket.
It should be:

```
norm([1/(x(1)*s+1), 1/(s+0.5); 3/(s+3), 1/(x(2)*s+2)],inf)
```

Also, you don't need `syms s`, `s = tf('s')` is enough.